# Uv unrapping an incredibly complex shape

Tags: uv, texture-baking

Firstly, I know that there are several other questions on here that are something like "how do I unwrap a complex shape" and its something they modelled with a couple hundred edges, but to be honest... the complexity I'm dealing with is on a whole different level and I need help:

I have this:
[image]

They're tracts from a brain found in an MRI.

The file was a .ply with per-vertex color in it.  I'm trying to uv unwrap and bake the colors so that I can export the file as an .obj with a material file so that my 3d printer software (which can handle several thousand colors, its a fancy printer) can print it (there's still other problems with the file prior to printing but that's a different question for here)

I know the basics of how to UV unwrapping and baking and have done so with this object several times, but every iteration kinda looks like this:
[image]

I.e. the colors end up in totally different spots and sometimes they look like they were kinda spray painted onto the object.

So my question specifically is:  what options/settings would you use when UV unwrapping to duplicate the colors as precisely as possible?

**EDIT:**

Per requested, wireframe images:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to help you much, but I think if you add a screenshot of the wireframe it might give some insight.
Also if you share your blend file someone might take a look directly.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati  Will do.  I forget, what's the official way to share blend files on here again?  I could just provide a onedrive link or something if necessary.  Will edit question to include wireframe in one sec

Comment: You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ to upload your blend file.

Comment: Have you tried just selecting all edges and marking them all as seams and then unwrapping and then baking? Have you tried baking a simple object first to see if you understand the baking process correctly? Have you tried increasing the resolution of your target texture for baking?

Comment: Consider that you have to clean up your geometry in the first place (removing all intersecting/inner geometry and fuse each part into one final piece) otherwise it isn't worth it to unwrap the model at all. Hard to give any advice based on the provided screenshots... at a first glance it looks like your UVs are a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure this is the way to do this, correct me if I'm wrong, but since you already have the objects textured, what you could do is

1. create a new UV map
2. unwrap your object whichever way you prefer to do it on the newly created UV map
3. you can bake the textures to the second UV

Comment: I'm sorry if my question wasn't clear... but step 2 in your answer is the problem.  I can unwrap and bake it, but none of them are being accurate.  I need help figuring out the "whichever way you prefer to do it" part in order to make it accurate enough.